# Is it possible to use a local variable in a label expression?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sql

Is it possible to use a local variable in a label expression/field calculator in QGIS 3? I have an extremely long CASE expression that generates a String for the labels of my objects, and I would like to process the string after I have generated it. To do this, however, I would need to save the string in a local variable and refer to the variable in the processing afterwards.

Here's a shortened version of my problem:

```
CASE when ("A" != 'null'  then 'A: ' ||  "A" || ', ' else '' end ||
CASE when ("B" != 'null' then 'B: ' ||  "B" || ', ' else '' end ||
CASE when ("C" != 'null' then 'C: ' ||  "C" || ', ' else '' end
```

This creates something like: "A: 3, B: 1, "

There's ", " always after the last variable and I would like to remove that from the end. The expression I'm using is so long that it exceeds the character limit of the field calculator. That's why I would like to save the string in a local variable "input", then use left(input, length(input) - 2). This would delete the last two ", " and make the string "A: 3, B: 1". It will have to be done like this because the table will be updated in the future.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not reword your expression so that the comma only appears with the second CASE statement? so when "A" != null then 'A: ' || "A"; case when B != null then ', B: ' || "B" .. .and so on

Comment: @she_weeds if "A" is `null`, then there'd be a comma at the beginning...@nintskari, did you try the *Expression Dialog*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the *Expression Dialog* in the *Labels* tab of the layer properties, you can add `CASE` expressions till the end of days...
Use double spaces following each string, `trim()` the trailing and `replace()` the others with `,`:

```
replace(
  trim(
    concat(
      CASE WHEN "A" != 'null' THEN 'A: ' || "A" || '  ' ELSE NULL END,
      <add_till_fingers_bleed>
    )
  ),
  '  ',
  ', '
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That actually does work! But I used a different workaround. I made it so that the ", " is at the beginning, then used trim(). Apparently, the length of trim() function doesn't have to be precise, so I could just use it to trim the first two characters.

Comment: @nintskari glad you found your way. just asking: `trim()` explicitly removes *whitespaces* at the start and end of a string...are you sure that those leading commas are removed?